# How to change X into different numbers?

Tags: java

I have the following code where I get the age:

```
while (get.hasNext())
{
    int data = get.nextInt();
    int age = (2017 - data);
    int X = (1);
    if(data==-1)
    {
        break;
    }  

    System.out.println("Case X: "+ age);
}
```

However, I don't know how to change the "X" into different numbers.  For example, if:

```
data = 1997;
```

The output should be:

> Case 1: 20

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give an example input and output.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You clearly already know about assignment. Are you asking how to *get* a number to assign to X? If so, where do you want to get it from?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? your code and question doesn't makes sense

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Also, this question is not about Windows or Netbeans.  I am thus removing both of those tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if I know you want this:

```
int X = 1;
while (get.hasNext()) {
    int data = get.nextInt();
    int age = (2017 - data);
    if(data==-1){
        break;

    }  
    System.out.println("Case " + X + ":"+ age);
    X = X + 1;
}
} }
```

Comment: Sorry english isn't my first language, and thanks for the answer

Comment: `case` is a reserved keyword, you can't use it as variable name.

Comment: @SamuelTulach  Just replace your variable `case` by `X` and remove the line `int x = (1);`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   int X = (1); 
while (get.hasNext()) {     
    int data = get.nextInt();
    int age = (2017 - data);
    if(data==-1){
        break;  
    }  
    System.out.println("Case "+ X +": "+ age);
    X = X + 1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Rather than just posting code, please consider adding a brief explanation of "how" the above solves the issue to make the answer more useful to others.